# Declare an interface in object pascal and use it as return value

Tags: delphi-7, delphi

Using Delphi 7. Here is an (incomplete) example that demonstrates my problem:

```
interface
uses Classes, Contnrs;

type
   IEditorModule = interface;
   procedure Method1;
   procedure Method2;
   end;

   TEditorModuleList = class(TList)
   protected
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): IEditorModule;
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; const Value: IEditorModule);
   public
    property  Items[Index: Integer]: IEditorModule
      read GetItem write SetItem; default;   
   end;

implementation

function TEditorModuleList.GetItem(Index: Integer): IEditorModule;
begin
  Result := IEditorModule(inherited Items[index]);
end;
```

Cannot compile this because I get this error:

[Error] LEditorModule.pas(73): Incompatible types: 'IEditorModule' and 'TObject'

The main reason for declaring a new TList descendant is to be able to do things like:

```
aModuleList[3].Method1;
```

What kind of syntax will allow me to cast an object to an interface (instead of a concrete class)? Facts:

- I cannot make TEditorModule a class. It needs to be an interface, because classes in totally different hierarchies will implement it.
- I need to have a class for storing references for a list of objects that implement the IEditorModule interface.

How do I do this?

Comment: You should use TInterfaceList for interfaces instead of TList. I believe it's available in Delphi 7.

Comment: your code compiles for me if you remove the ";" after the word interface and implement setitem.

Comment: TInterfaceList works! Although I'm not sure why is it not possible to cast an interface to an object or back. They are both represented as pointers, so what is the reason? Graymatter, I would accept your soulution please post it as an answer.

Comment: The reason interface pointer and object pointers are not interchangeable is that interfaces are reference counted (i.e. managed types) and classes are not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to use TInterfaceList for interfaces. It is available in Delphi 7. There is some logic built into TInterfaceList to manage reference counts for example setting them to nil them when clearing the list.

If you look at the code behind TInterfaceList you will see some of the actions that take place.

One thing you should be a bit careful of is that TInterfaceList uses TThreadList internally so there is a bit of overhead where it locks and unlocks the list.